# How to convert this sorted map method from java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

How do I convert the following Java to Kotlin?

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> example(List<Dto> dtos) {

    if (dtos.isEmpty()) {
        return ImmutableMap.of();
    }

    final Map<String, Map<String, String>> outerMapByField1 = new TreeMap<>();

    dtos.forEach(dto -> {

        final String field1 = dto.getField1();

        final Map<String, String> innerMapByField2 = outerMapByField1.computeIfAbsent(field1, (key) -> new TreeMap<>());
        innerMapByField2.put(dto.getField2(), dto.getField3());

    });

    return outerMapByField1;

}
```

The IntelliJ conversion gives me something to work with and my attempt to refactor it has ended up with the following, which does not compile.

```
private fun example(dtos: List<Dto>): Map<String, Map<String, String>> {

    if (dtos.isEmpty()) {
        return ImmutableMap.of()
    }

    val outerMapByField1 = sortedMapOf<String, Map<String, String>>()

    dtos.forEach { dto ->

        val field1 = dto.field1

        val innerMapByField2 = outerMapByField1.getOrPut(field1) { key -> TreeMap() }
        innerMapByField2.put(dto.field2, dto.field3)

    }

    return outerMapByField1

}
```

Comment: Please post the compiler error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, the values in your `outerMapByField1` are [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) instances, which is a read-only interface. To modify these maps, you need to store them as [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html)s (as per @Heinrisch's answer).
- Kotlin offers an [`emptyMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-map.html) function that you might consider using instead of `ImmutableMap.of()`.
- The lamda passed to [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) doesn't take an argument, so you have to remove `key ->`.

Here's all these applied:

```
private fun example(dtos: List<Dto>): Map<String, Map<String, String>> {

    if (dtos.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyMap()
    }

    val outerMapByField1 = sortedMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, String>>()

    dtos.forEach { dto ->

        val field1 = dto.field1

        val innerMapByField2 = outerMapByField1.getOrPut(field1) { TreeMap() }
        innerMapByField2.put(dto.field2, dto.field3)

    }

    return outerMapByField1

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maps are not mutable by default in Kotlin, so adding some mutability will make it compile:

```
 private fun example(dtos: List<Dto>): Map<String, Map<String, String>> {

        if (dtos.isEmpty()) {
            return emptyMap()
        }

        val outerMapByField1 = sortedMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, String>>()

        dtos.forEach { dto ->

            val field1 = dto.field1

            val innerMapByField2 = outerMapByField1.getOrPut(field1) { mutableMapOf() }
            innerMapByField2.put(dto.field2, dto.field3)

        }

        return outerMapByField1

    }
```

Maybe something like this:

```
private fun example(dtos: List<Dto>) = dtos.groupBy { it.field1 }.map { entry ->
    entry.key to entry.value.associateBy { it.field2 }.mapValues { it.value.field3 }.toSortedMap()
}.toMap().toSortedMap()
```

Comment: Many thanks. That's on the right track. Just one issue. The inner map also has to be sorted. So, TreeMap instead of mutableMapOf().

Comment: @KevinStembridge I don't know why you want sorted maps, but added a more functional solution.